# Failed to access remote package built by Drools Workbench 6.3.0.Final on different server

Tags: java, drools

I want to load kjar runtime from remote repository in simple client java web project. 
For that I followed below steps -
1. We downloaded kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.3.0.Final-wildfly8.war(deployed as jboss as kie-drools-6.3.0 on wildfly). I created project  'Test1' & successfully build & deployed.
2. In "Artifact Repository" I can see my project jar "Test1-LATEST.jar" & even I can download it like -
 http://localhost:8081/kie-drools-6.3.0/maven2/com/eno/Test1/LATEST/Test1-LATEST.jar 
3. Now I tried to load jar from client simple java project but it failed with following exception

```
11:12:33,961 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (default task-95) KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=com.eno:Test1:LATEST]
11:12:33,961 INFO  [stdout] (default task-95) KieModule ReleaseId:com.eno:Test1:LATEST
11:12:33,962 WARN  [org.kie.scanner.MavenRepository] (default task-95) Unable to resolve artifact: com.eno:Test1:LATEST
11:12:33,963 WARN  [org.kie.scanner.MavenRepository] (default task-95) Unable to resolve artifact: com.eno:Test1:pom:LATEST
11:12:33,963 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95) java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: com.eno:Test1:LATEST
11:12:33,963 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:117)
11:12:33,963 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:111)
11:12:33,963 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at com.eno.testweb.TestDrool6.doPost(TestDrool6.java:59)
11:12:33,963 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at com.eno.testweb.TestDrool6.doGet(TestDrool6.java:38)
11:12:33,963 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
11:12:33,964 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
11:12:33,965 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
11:12:33,966 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
11:12:33,966 ERROR [stderr] (default task-95)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I used below code. Also included all 6.3.0.Final distribution jars in project :

```
String url = "http://localhost:8081/kie-drools-6.3.0/maven2/com/eno/Test1/LATEST/Test1-LATEST.jar";
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
System.out.println(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());
UrlResource urlResource = (UrlResource) ks.getResources().newUrlResource(url);
urlResource.setUsername("app-admin");
urlResource.setPassword("app-password");
urlResource.setBasicAuthentication("enabled");
InputStream is = urlResource.getInputStream();
KieModule kModule = kr.addKieModule(ks.getResources().newInputStreamResource(is));
System.out.println(kModule.getReleaseId());
KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kModule.getReleaseId()); //Failed at this line
```

pom.xml file in Test1-LATEST.jar is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.eno</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test1</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
  <name>Test1</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.eno</groupId>
      <artifactId>pojo</artifactId>
      <version>26.9.15</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

setting.xml : Added system property kie.maven.settings.custom=/home/krunal/devtool/drool6/settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
     <server>  
      <id>uf-playground</id>
      <username>app-admin</username>
      <password>app-password</password>
      <configuration>
        <wagonProvider>httpclient</wagonProvider>
        <httpConfiguration>
          <all>
            <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
          </all>
        </httpConfiguration>
      </configuration>
    </server>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>uf-playground</id>
                    <name>Drools workbench</name>
                    <url>http://localhost:8081/kie-drools-6.3/maven2</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I'm confused as you set the repo's usr+password both in custom maven settings file, as well as to programmatically download the .jar via code?

For the code, I would try to separate first try to load a .jar you downloaded manually, so to make sure your KIE API usage is working fine, then test separately the authenticated InputStream Java side is also OK.

If instead you are trying to connect to repo in authenticated mode directly via maven, the Java code should be modified accordingly to KIE examples like the `4.2.6.5. KieContainer from KieRepository` I think..

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I solved this issue. Problem is in setting.xml. Actually I used <server>xxx</server>. Correct way is <servers><server>xxx</server></servers>. Yes, you are right I removed code of programmatically download the .jar.